# Beautiful Soup: Copy a table to a new file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to isolate a specific `<table>` element and put it in a new file. The table has an id, `ModelTable`, and I can find it using `soup.select("#ModelTable")` ("soup" being the imported file).

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the element into a new file. Simply writing it to a new file (as in: `write(soup.select("#ModelTable")` ) doesn't work, as it's not a string object, and converting it with `str()` results in a string enclosed in brackets.

Ideally I'd like to be able to export the isolated element after running it through `.prettify()` so that I can get a good HTML file right off the bat. I know I must be missing something obvious... any hints?

Comment: Did `write(soup.select("ModelTable").prettify())` not work?

Comment: `write(soup.select("ModelTable").prettify())` gives an error: `'list' object has no attribute 'prettify'`

Comment: Right, sorry, I'll write out the full answer, because I'm pretty sure it'd work if you iterate over the parts you want to write to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the contents of the returned object. Your question also taught me that BS4's `.select` uses CSS selectors, which is fantastic.

```
with open('file_output.html', 'w') as f:
  for tag in soup.select("#ModelTable"):
    f.write(tag.prettify())
```

Comment: The missing piece! Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a mistake in the code, though, "ModelTable" should be "#ModelTable"